# Review a solution for second order partial derivative.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Check please my solution for second derivative. If it's not correct, what are my mistakes?

```
z=ctg(y/x)
```

$\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{y}{sin^2(\frac{y}{x})*x^2}$

$\frac{dz}{dy} = \frac{-1}{sin^2(\frac{y}{x})*x}$

[A solution for second order derivatives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ozxj.jpg)

$
z''xx = y * (\frac{1}{sin^2(\frac{y}{x})*x^2})' = y* \frac{0-sin^2(y/x)*x^2}{(sin^2(\frac{y}{x})*x^2)^2}- = \frac{y*(-2*sin(y/x)*2x)}{sin^4(\frac{y}{x})*x^4} =
\frac{-y*4x*sin(\frac{y}{x})}{sin^4(\frac{y}{x})*x^4}
$

Comment: Please include your solution *within* your post.  We really prefer not to have to chase links. And checking out the image, it's impossible to read, as is.

Comment: Ok, but it will take some time

Comment: Fix the notation in order follow your solution

Comment: If you attempt, I will help fine tune it, @Dmitri, via an edit.

Comment: Does that look like what you wrote, just to be sure?

Comment: Edited a post with more description for solution.

Comment: Thanks, @Dmitri!

Comment: @amWhy, there was a typo in first order derivatives, sorry, fixed it